# Initiating Skype call from HTML and recording the call duration

Tags: python, django, skype, skype4py

I am trying to integrate the possibility to initiate skype calls chats from my django app all i've found on the official developer.skype is how to add the skypeBoutton that enables me to call other skype user without being able to get informations like the call duration and other functionalities.(https://developer.skype.com/skype-uris/skype-uri-tutorial-webpages#_skypeButtons)
IS there any way to get these functionalities or any skype api wrapper available for django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skype buttons are plain HTML and JavaScript and can be integrated to any website. There is no need to wrap this functionality, as you can simply embed it to you Django templates.

You most likely do not want to integrate `skype4py` for Django application, as this library is meant for automatizing incoming Skype messages and calls when running a Skype on a headless server, not initiating calls or chats with users.

Comment: what i really want to do in my web app a user can call an expert using skype and then i can retrieve the skype call duration in order to bill him
is that possible?

Comment: As Microsoft is dropping Skype desktop API, it is not possible soon (though it is possible right now). Skype is a black box. If you want to have automatized APIs to your call data, the easiest way to achieve this is WebRTC http://www.webrtc.org/ and setting up your own open source call stack.

Comment: I suggest your experts simple manually record this information to a database if you do not look alternative for Skype.

Comment: thanks a lot.i will give the webRTC a try.